# Did Kaner patent the LightScribe procedure to synthesize graphene?

Tags: patentability, licensing

They describe the procedure in [Science](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/335/6074/1326.short).

Did they patent the method? I can't find anything on Kaners Google Scholar page, but maybe somebody knows more.

Essentially, can we start a business and sell graphene based on their method?

Comment: didn't know it exists. And yes, I found it on a coauthors page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they did: United States Patent Application 61/606,637

Comment: That is the number of a provisional application. If that is all there is it is not patented yet and there is no way to tell if a patent will ever issue.

Comment: Can this provisional application be viewed? I tried to [search for patents](http://www.uspto.gov/patents/process/search/), but I'm unable to figure out where to enter what.

Comment: Should work on Public PAIR http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair however it is typically Government-issued-bureaucratically finicky and requires numbers to be entered by some incomprehensible logic for commas, slashes, etc - I couldn't find it by this application number.

Comment: I confirm it's not findable... How demotivating.

Comment: As I said, it is a provisional application. They are not ever technically "published" but do become viewable if a non-provisional application associated with them is published or results in a granted patent. The 61/ series is what lets you know it is a provisional application. Even a non-provisional application might not be published for 18 months from its earliest priority date.

Comment: OK. I thought also applications are viewable.